How to compute mean and covariance for repeated transformation of random matrices?
I have a random matrix $M$, which in practice is vectorized/flattened and represented as a multivariate Gaussian, so I know the mean and covariance of $M$. Consider the following system:
$$ X_{t+1} = M_t X_t$$
I am given $X_t$ (which is known and not random), and I want to compute the distribution for $X_{t+1}$. Here, $M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix and $x$ is an $n \times m$ matrix.
Probably not relevant, but $M$ is a block matrix, which is $2 \times 2$ of submatrices and $X$ is a block matrix, which is $2 \times 1$ of submatrices.
I would apply this equation repeatedly, and I want to estimate the mean and covariance each time.

This is probably not a full answer, but unless I'm missing something since $M$ is multivariate Gaussian, $X_{t+1}$ is entry-wise a linear combination of entries of $M$ with known coefficients, so a flattened version of $X_{t+1}$ is some just some linear transformation $A_t$ whose coefficients will depend deterministically on $X_t$. So the mean in this flattened setting is $A_t$ times the mean of $M$, with covariance matrix $A_t^\top C A_t$, with $C$ the covariance matrix of $M$.

Of course, that doesn't handle the bookkeeping of actually doing the flattening and computing $A_t$ and soforth
